# Share Image from Xiaomi gallery app has problem

Tags: android, image, uri, xiaomi, miui

I want to share images from MIUI gallery app to my app but received intent has `data=null` and
`uri=content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.miui.gallery%2Fcache%2FSecurityShare%2F1657350098978.jpg`

Then i use `Cursor` to get file path and path is:
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.miui.gallery/cache/SecurityShare/1657350098978.jpg`

As you see, it shares from its data folder, So my app can not reach the file. This is happening only for images and only in Xiomi MIUI gallery app.

This is my manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ReceiveShareActivity"
            android:configChanges="uiMode"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this is my code:

```
Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID};
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID;

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE + ">0", null, orderBy);
```

Comment: Dont try to get a 'path'. Not needed. Just use the uri directly.

Comment: @blackapps yes it worked, i tried it with inputstream and it worked. thanks a lot

Comment: Is it impossible to get path of the actual files like storage/0/DCIM/camera/me.jpg ?  Because i need to deal with this kn react native and I dont want to recreate the files using stream

Comment: @PrieyudhaAkaditaS it is passed but i think that it gave me forribeden access

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: @MohdSakibSyed i just used inputstream with that uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @blackapps, I tried with `Inputstream` with URI and it works well.